# Comparing different rows inside a data frame and removing unnecessary rows: df.apply and index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I am comparing values in different rows within a data frame. If a row from the data frame matches any other row(s) by at least 75%, I will keep the original one and remove the others.

The original data frame looks like this:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 11213 | I am going to the cinema |
| 23213 | Black is my favourite colour |
| 35455 | I am going to the cinema with you |
| 421323 | My friends think I am a good guy |

The desired output would be:

| ID | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 11213 | I am going to the cinema |
| 23213 | Black is my favourite colour |
| 421323 | My friends think I am a good guy |

For that, I am looping over a data frame using df.apply twice to find out which rows match. My plan is to get indices of the rows that match and remove them. However, after iterating through the data frame using df.apply, the indices do not match which produces an error.

So far I have been able to come up with this:

```
def compare(text):
    match = df.apply(lambda row: (fuzz.partial_ratio(row['text'], text) >= 75), axis=1)
    return [i for i, x in enumerate(matching) if x]


df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", dtype=str, lineterminator='\n')

result = df.apply(lambda row: compare(row['text']).reset_index(), axis=1)
result.to_csv(f'output.csv', index=False)
```

Which enables me to get indices of the rows that match (though for some reason the index is +2 difference to the original data frame), but I am not sure how to proceed and delete the ones that satisfy the criterion while keeping the original rows only.

My goal is to keep the original indices and find a better way to remove rows where row['text'] are 75% similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using a comparison df:

```
df_compare = pd.DataFrame(
            df['Text'].apply(lambda row: max([fuzz.partial_ratio(row, x), i] 
                            for i, x in enumerate(df['Text']) if x != row)
                        ).to_list(),
                        columns=['ratio', 'closest']
            )
```

This gives you:

```
   ratio  closest
0    100        2
1     38        0
2    100        0
3     42        2
```

Then you can filter your initial df using `df_compare`:

```
df[~((df_compare['ratio']>=75) & (df_compare['closest'] < df_compare.index))]
```

Output:

```
       ID                              Text
0   11213          I am going to the cinema
1   23213      Black is my favourite colour
3  421323  My friends think I am a good guy
```

#### Edit:

Computing a full comparison matrix would give you the same result:

```
df_compare = pd.DataFrame(
            df['Text'].apply(lambda row: [fuzz.partial_ratio(x, row)
                            for x in df['Text']]
                        ).to_list()
            )

for i in df_compare.index:
    for j in df_compare.columns[i:]:
        df_compare.iloc[i,j] = 0
```

This gives the following:

```
     0   1   2  3
0    0   0   0  0
1   38   0   0  0
2  100  33   0  0
3   42  36  41  0
```

You can finally filter with:

```
df[df_compare.max(axis=1)<75]
```